# How to pass data from script.js to express.js

Tags: javascript, express

This is a basic registration form.
script.js performs input checking.
express.js sends and receives data from mongodb.

What I need to do is send input values (such as username.value) after input checking from script.js to express.js. How do I do it?

things to keep in mind this is an assignment and I cannot use jQuery, React etc. just HTML, CSS, JS, Express and mongodb

Comment: send values with a POST request, don't need libs to do that

Comment: Can you direct me to some syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API to do a POST request and capture it with express.

The [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/FormData) API works well for getting the data out of a form.

Example:

```js
fetch(/* POST endpoint */, {
    body: new FormData(/* form element */),
    method: 'POST'
});
```